# Ground state term symbol, why is $L = |M_L|$, if $L$ must be a maximum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, orbitals, quantum-chemistry

I'm trying to understand how to predict ground state term symbol of atoms.

After finding the biggest S, why the biggest $L$ will be $L = |M_L|$, where $M_L = \sum m_l$?
I know this rule works to predict the total $L$, but it doesn't make sense to me that it will give the biggest $L$, to me it seems like this is the minimum $L$.

For example, the nitrogen atom has three electrons in 2p.

Following the first rule, the spin $S$ of the ground state will be the maximum possible, which is S = 3/2.

The second rule, according to some books is to maximize $M_L$, in the case of Nitrogen, according to Pauli principle, since all the spins are up, we can only get $M_L = 0$.

Now, all material I read says that $L$ of the ground state will be the maximum one, so $L = |M_L|$, but if we expand the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients of the three states:
$|1 \,\,\,\, 0> |1 -1> |1 \,\,\,\, 1>$ we get the possibility of L = 3,2,1 and 0, so why is $L=0$ the maximum possible value?

There is an amazing answer to this [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/63261/85284), but he doesn't explain why he cuts out the the terms with bigger $L$.